# onKeyup in chosen angular

Tags: angularjs, jquery-chosen

I have a chosen in angular. Currently it fetches the samples on load. I want to fetch the samples list when user Enters at least 3 digits.(Want to use the entered value in mysql where). Now the keyup is not working.

```
<select class="sel-bx" ng-keyup="getSampleIds()"
    chosen dataload="aSampleidList.length" 
    multiple selecteditm="sampleIdList" 
    ng-model="sampleIdList" 
    ng-options="sampleIds.sample_id as sampleIds.sample_id for sampleIds in aSampleidList | unique:'sample_id'"
    data-placeholder=" ">
</select>
```

Comment: Please share controller code

Comment: please do add `getSampleIds` method code